# Help locating a file in Magento that contains HTML

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm trying to change the class name in the HTML output from "price". I was hoping to find it in the code block below.

The following code (frontend/default/theme/template/page/html/cart.phtml):

```
<div class="shopping_cart_b">
    <a href="#" class="open">
        <?php echo $this->__('Shopping Cart:'); ?>
        <?php echo $_cartQty; ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Item(s) - '); ?></span>

        <?php if ($this->canApplyMsrp()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>
            <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
                (<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </a>
</div>
```

Produces the following output (in Header):

```
<div class="shopping_cart_b">
    <a href="#" class="open">
        Shopping Cart: 
            <span>Item(s) - </span>
            <span class="price">£0.00</span>                                     
    </a>
</div>
```

Block Name Hint:

```
Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar
```

I've determined that `<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>` is responsible for calling `<span class="price">£0.00</span>`, but I've no idea where to find the actual file to change the CSS class.

I've used `grep` to try and find the file, but there are too many results. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Enable path hints

Comment: That just leads me back to the file containing the block of code I have already provided.

Comment: If you have the block name you should find it, please add exactly the page  where you want to add your class cart, product list etc... i Will look that tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is something that you won't find in a phtml file.  The magento helper function has a second parameter that is by default, set `true`.  The parameter, I believe is whether to include the `container` or not.  The container, if my memory is correct, is where html is being included and perhaps the class name is within the code.  I strongly suggest NOT updating the code, but rather apply a second parameter of `false` and see what sort of output you can then work with.  If what I say is correct, it should be simply the price.  Therefore, try this as a solution:

```
<span class="price price-customclass"><?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal(), false) ?></span>
```

I strongly suggest to append your new class name, instead of replacing the original.  Keeping the original class name `price` would be helpful to ensure that anything referencing or depending on that class is not affected.

**CORRECTION**

The code above is incorrectly assumed, but ultimately correct if you trace the function calls.  The call I have in the code snippet actually doesn't allow for a second parameter.  Tracing call hierarchy reveals that you may substitute that code with:

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getStore()->formatPrice($price, false);
```

**UPDATE**

As I had suggested above, the class name is, in fact, applied by code not found within a template file.  The code below was found within: `magento/app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php`

```
   if ($includeContainer) {
            return '<span class="price">' . ($addBrackets ? '[' : '') . $this->formatTxt($price, $options) .
                ($addBrackets ? ']' : '') . '</span>';
        }
```